# How can I add the image to the Excel Sheet while Exporting from Gridview to Excel

Tags: c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I have a asp.net application in that I have grid view and I export that grid-view data into Excel it is working fine. But, now I want add the image(image getting from Server map-path) to the Excel sheet while export grid view data to Excel

How can I bind the image to excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, i have tested it on `local IIS`, it is working properly and including the image like `Header Image/Logo` on top of the grid data.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";        
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls;");                
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();        
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);        
dgrExport.DataSource = dtExport;        
dgrExport.DataBind();
dgrExport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
string headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td><img src=""D:\\Folder\\1.jpg"" \></td></tr></Table>";
Response.Write(headerTable);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());        
Response.End();
```

you can adjust your image's height and width as per your requirement. Same height and width setting will be required for the `<TD>` tag.